# razor pages handler with checkbox boolean doesn't bind

Tags: asp.net-core, razor-pages, asp.net-core-2.2

I have a form with several inputs. I send the form per ajax with Jquery's `form.serialize()`. The network tab shows that the data is sent successfully (`welcomesCritiques: on, complete: on`).

On the server side I catch those inputs in a custom handler

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostLoadBooksAsync(string search, bool welcomesCritiques, bool complete, int startIndex, int amount)
```

The string and the ints bind perfectly fine. But the bools are always false. When I replace the bools with a string, I get "on".

Is this a known issue? How can I make "on" become a bool?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To bind to a boolean, you need to set the value to "true", not the default, which is "on":

```
<input type="checkbox" name="welcomesCritiques" value="true" />
```

The value will only be submitted if the checkbox is checked. If no value is provided for the handler parameter, it will default to `false`.

See more about checkboxes in Razor forms here: https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/forms/checkboxes

Comment: Oh I get it, how strange. I actually visited that website, but didn't realize I had to e.g. use a hidden field with "true/false" with the checkbox. Case closed, many thanks!

Comment: @Doidel The hidden field is generated by the Tag Helper. If you aren't using a tag helper, you don't need to include a hidden field.

Comment: But somehow I'll have to map the input's "on" to "true/false", otherwise it won't be parsed by the handler, right?  Not necessarily with a hidden field, but in some way I'll have to do it. Or, alternatively, accept my bools as strings in the handler, and convert the "On" myself.

Comment: @Doidel No - you preset the `value` attribute to `true`. See the edited answer

Comment: Aaah I got it, thanks for clarifying! Works like a charm, much appreciated!